# Deshabilitar Formulario o boton por periodos

Tags: php, javascript

Buen dia, tengo un formulario el cual solo debe estar disponible por ejemplo un dia a la semana de 9 am a 1 pm, estoy buscando una opcion para poder llevar a cabo esto, no se si esto sea posible, me podrian orientar por favor.

Comment: Si es posible. Habría muchas formas de hacerlo, ¿Usas php puro?

Comment: Es posible pero agrega detalles de lo que has realizado por favor, revisar  [ask]..

Comment: Hasta el momento no tengo codigo, como les comento la verdad no sabia si quiera si era posible hacerlo, uso si uso php, me podrian dar una idea de como se podria hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
//Sacas la hora (Recuerda que es la hora del servidor)
$hora = date('H');

//Haces un simple comparativo entre los rangos que quieres que este disponible
if( $hora >= 9 && $hora < 13 ){
    echo '<button type="button">Enviar</button>';
}else{
    echo '<button type="button" disabled>Enviar</button>';
}
?>
```

Te dejé el código comentado, esto se puede hacer en una línea con un if ternario pero te confundiría más tomando en cuenta que eres novato.

**ANEXO SOLUCIÓN**

Cómo comenta **Shaz**, lo ideal sería no mostrar el botón, por lo que el else está de más.

```
<?php
//Sacas la hora (Recuerda que es la hora del servidor)
$hora = date('H');

//Haces un simple comparativo entre los rangos que quieres que este disponible
if( $hora >= 9 && $hora < 13 ){
    echo '<button type="button">Enviar</button>';
}
?>
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Pero usar el atributo disabled no es una buena idea en este caso. y menos tanta lógica en PHP para eso, la idea sería precisamente no mostrarle un botón fuera de dicho horario.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda ya pude hacerlo.